# ¿Porque unicamente me lee el ultimo fichero del directorio? PHP

Tags: php

Tengo 2 codigos, uno que me lee todos los ficheros de una carpeta y otro que solo me 
arroja el ultimo fichero de dicha carpeta, lo que no entiendo es en que se basa para dar resultados diferentes ya que según mi lógica ambos códigos funcionan igual, pero arrojan resultados diferentes. Me gustaria que no propusieran codigos diferentes ya que mi objetivo es hallar el porque en el primer codigo me arroja solo el ultimo fichero y en el otro si me arreoja todos

Codigo que me arroja unicamente el ultimo fichero del directorio

```
$carpetaabierta = opendir('micarpeta');
     if ($carpetaabierta) {  
        while (false !== readdir($carpetaabierta)) {
            $leercarpeta = readdir($carpetaabierta);
            if ($leercarpeta !=='.'&& $leercarpeta !== '..') {
                echo $leercarpeta.'<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Me arroja todos los ficheros del directorio

```
 $carpetaabierta = opendir('micarpeta');
    if ($carpetaabierta) {  
        while ( false !== $leercarpeta= readdir($carpetaabierta)) {
            if ($leercarpeta !=='.'&& $leercarpeta !== '..') {
                echo $leercarpeta.'<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El el primero estas leyendo 2 veces la carpeta (`readdir`) y en el segundo solo 1 vez. ¿Tu directorio tiene 2 archivos?

Comment: Exacto tiene 2 archivos

Comment: El problema no es que te muestra solo el último, si tuvieras 4, solo imprimirá 2, y así. Ahora publico una respuesta.

Comment: Ohhhhh en pocas palabras se esta saltando uno dado, qu lo lee dos veces dentro del while, pero intente declarar la variable por fuera y el index no ejecuta se congela, la verdad soy muy novato en esto recien estoy aprendiendo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comportamiendo se debe a que en el primer código llamas 2 veces a la función [`readdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readdir.php), la cual:

> Devuelve el nombre de la siguiente entrada del directorio. Las entradas son devueltas en el orden en que fueron almacenadas por el sistema de ficheros.

Lo que hace es, por cada llamada a esta, mueve el puntero al siguiente valor.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tu directorio contiene:

```
Archivo:    [".", "..", "archivo1", "archivo2"]
Puntero:      ^
```

Al llamarla por primera vez, devolverá "." y moverá el indicador al siguiente registro:

```
Archivo:    [".", "..", "archivo1", "archivo2"]
Puntero:           ^
```

En resumen, al llamar 2 veces, te estas saltando un archivo en cada iteración.
Es por esto que lo correcto sería utilizar el segundo código.

---

Si la intención es obtener todos los archivo (*y no buscar uno puntual*) podrías emplear [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
$archivos = scandir('micarpeta');
foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
    if ($archivo !=='.'&& $archivo !== '..') {
        echo $archivo.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente eso era muchas gracias